# BIND9 Dynamic Update not working - NOTZONE and SERVFAIL errors

Tags: dhcp, centos7, bind9

This is on CentOS 7 with BIND9. When I run nsupdate to test ddns updating, I get a couple levels of failure. On adding the reverse zone, I get . Then on adding the forward zone entry, I get . I've reached the end of google in trying to identify what I'm doing wrong - does anyone see what's the problem here? I'm  not even getting into DHCPD yet, though I have it all configured and ready to go.

```
nsupdate
> server ns1.office.somecompany.com
> key rndc-key xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==
> zone office.somecompany.com.
> update add 55.4.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 600 IN PTR stinky.office.somecompany.com.
> send
update failed: NOTZONE
> update add stinky.office.somecompany.com. 600 IN A 192.168.4.55
> send
update failed: SERVFAIL
```

If I put the above commands into a file (test.bind.ddns) and add the debug switch, my output, to me, is no more helpful:

```
[root@ns1 ~]# nsupdate -d test.bind.ddns
Sending update to 192.168.4.25#53
Outgoing update query:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: UPDATE, status: NOERROR, id:   2851
;; flags:; ZONE: 1, PREREQ: 0, UPDATE: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; ZONE SECTION:
;office.somecompany.com. IN    SOA

;; UPDATE SECTION:
55.4.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 600  IN      PTR     stinky.office.somecompany.com.

;; TSIG PSEUDOSECTION:
rndc-key.               0       ANY     TSIG    hmac-md5.sig-alg.reg.int. 1424040289 300 16 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa== 2851 NOERROR 0


Reply from update query:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: UPDATE, status: NOTZONE, id:   2851
;; flags: qr ra; ZONE: 1, PREREQ: 0, UPDATE: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; ZONE SECTION:
;office.somecompany.com. IN    SOA

;; TSIG PSEUDOSECTION:
rndc-key.               0       ANY     TSIG    hmac-md5.sig-alg.reg.int. 1424040289 300 16 bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb== 2851 NOERROR 0

Sending update to 192.168.4.25#53
Outgoing update query:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: UPDATE, status: NOERROR, id:  13185
;; flags:; ZONE: 1, PREREQ: 0, UPDATE: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; ZONE SECTION:
;office.somecompany.com. IN    SOA

;; UPDATE SECTION:
stinky.office.somecompany.com. 600 IN A 192.168.4.55

;; TSIG PSEUDOSECTION:
rndc-key.               0       ANY     TSIG    hmac-md5.sig-alg.reg.int. 1424040289 300 16 cccccccccccccccccccccc== 13185 NOERROR 0


Reply from update query:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: UPDATE, status: SERVFAIL, id:  13185
;; flags: qr ra; ZONE: 1, PREREQ: 0, UPDATE: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; ZONE SECTION:
;office.somecompany.com. IN    SOA

;; TSIG PSEUDOSECTION:
rndc-key.               0       ANY     TSIG    hmac-md5.sig-alg.reg.int. 1424040289 300 16 dddddddddddddddddddddd== 13185 NOERROR 0

Sending update to 192.168.4.25#53
Outgoing update query:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: UPDATE, status: NOERROR, id:  56384
;; flags:; ZONE: 1, PREREQ: 0, UPDATE: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; ZONE SECTION:
;office.somecompany.com. IN    SOA

;; TSIG PSEUDOSECTION:
rndc-key.               0       ANY     TSIG    hmac-md5.sig-alg.reg.int. 1424040289 300 16 ffffffffffffffffffffff== 56384 NOERROR 0


Reply from update query:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: UPDATE, status: NOERROR, id:  56384
;; flags: qr ra; ZONE: 1, PREREQ: 0, UPDATE: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; ZONE SECTION:
;office.somecompany.com. IN    SOA

;; TSIG PSEUDOSECTION:
rndc-key.               0       ANY     TSIG    hmac-md5.sig-alg.reg.int. 1424040289 300 16 gggggggggggggggggggggg== 56384 NOERROR 0

[root@ns1 ~]#
```

Here are the config files:

/etc/named.conf

```
options {
 directory "/var/named";
 recursion yes;
 allow-recursion { trusted; };
 listen-on { 192.168.4.25; };
 allow-query { 192.168.4/24; 127.0.0.1; };
 allow-transfer { 192.168.4/24; 127.0.0.1; };
 forwarders {
  8.8.8.8;
  8.8.4.4;
  };
 };

key "rndc-key" {
 algorithm hmac-md5;
 secret "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==";
 };

acl "trusted" {
 192.168.4.0/24;
 };

zone "." IN {
 type hint;
 file "named.ca";
 };

# forward lookup
zone "office.somecompany.com" {
 type master;
 file "/var/named/forward.office.somecompany.com";
 allow-update { key rndc-key; };
 };

# reverse lookup
zone "168.192.4.in-addr.arpa" {
 type master;
 file "/var/named/reverse.office.somecompany.com";
 allow-update { key rndc-key; };
 };
```

/var/named/reverse.office.somecompany.com

```
$TTL 604800
@ IN SOA office.somecompany.com. tj.hooker.us. (
 2015021503     ; Serial YYYYMMDD0x
 604800         ; Refresh (1 week)
 86400          ; Retry (1 day)
 2419200        ; Expire (4 weeks)
 604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL (1 week)
; name servers
 IN NS ns1.office.somecompany.com.
 IN NS ns2.office.somecompany.com.
; PTR records
25 IN PTR ns1.office.somecompany.com.
26 IN PTR ns2.office.somecompany.com.
14 IN PTR fileserv01.office.somecompany.com.
```

/var/named/forward.office.somecompany.com

```
$TTL    604800
@ IN SOA ns1.office.somecompany.com. tj.hooker.us. (
 2015021511     ; Serial YYYYMMDD1x
 604800         ; Refresh (1 week)
 86400          ; Retry (1 day)
 2419200        ; Expire (4 weeks)
 604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL (1 week)
; name servers - NS records
 IN NS ns1.office.somecompany.com.
 IN NS ns2.office.somecompany.com.
; A records for name servers
ns1.office.somecompany.com. IN A 192.168.4.25
ns2.office.somecompany.com. IN A 192.168.4.26
; Other A records
fileserv01.office.somecompany.com. IN A 192.168.4.14
```

named-chezkconfig and named-checkzone   are no longer reporting error, but I've been working on this for weeks and still not getting it to dynamically update the DNS. Any clues?
Thanks,
-Jeff

Comment: Were you ever able to figure out your problem? I am having a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just a tip: I had the same problem. I solved it by removing the .jnl file that bind generates.

Comment: Indeed, once in a while bind9 doesn't properly refresh the zone and you have to remove that file and restart.